# Skipping the initial animation of a line chart

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to skip the initial animation?

I've tried setting duration to 0 and then changing it to 2000.
But it seems that permanently disables animations until i destroy and recreate the chart.

What I'm trying to do:

- Initially display a line-chart with a flat line in the middle of graph.
- Then on data change i want it to animate to data positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initially set the animation duration to `0` and then either:

1. immediately set the animation duration, or
2. specify the duration when calling the `update()` method.

**Example:**

```js
let max = 10,
  min = -10,
  myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'series1',
        data: [5, 5, 5]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            max: 10,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 0
      }
    }
  });

// 1. immediately set the animation duration.
//myChart.config.options.animation.duration = 1000;

setInterval(function() {
  let a = getRandomInt(0, 3), // index to modify.
    b = getRandomInt(0, 11); // new value.
  myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data[a] = b;
  myChart.update(1000); // 2. specify the duration.
}, 2000); // update the chart every 2 seconds with a random value.

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit annoyed i have to set the duration on the update call everytime, since what i'm doing is taking it from the config already on the chart instance. 
But my problem is solved and thats the most important part :+1